# The butcher array of explicit Runge- Kutta method

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, runge-kutta-methods

Just a quick question, for a family of explicit Runge-Kutta methods parametrized by order q, by applying up to $p-1$ passes of deferred correction to p steps of Euler's method. When $p=2$, should its butcher array be 3x3 or 4x4?

Comment: It will be 3x3.